# RSpec / FactoryGirl - Rails STI - equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, single-table-inheritance

Simplified Example:

I recently setup `Single Table Inheritance` on an `Animal` model. `Cat` and `Dog` are subclasses of `Animal`.

I have an `Animal` factory :

`factory :animal do
  type { ["Dog","Cat"] }.sample
end`

Almost everywhere in my test suite I call
`let(:animal) { Factory.create(:animal) }` because the type of `Animal` is irrelevant for the test. Since moving to STI I am getting errors where I perform equality checks on these animals because the superclass `Animal` is returned by the factory but when associated objects instantiate `Animal` they return the subclass.

Example:
`expect(zoo.animal).to eq(animal)` fails with:

`expected: #<Cat:0x007fa01a8cd360 same_other_attributes...>
actual: #<Animal:0x007fa01b8d33b8 same_other_attributes...>`

Is there a way I can change the `Animal` factory to return an instance of its subclass?

I did try calling `.reload` on the `Animal` after the factory creates it but it did not trigger reloading the new (sub)class. I know normally you can call `superclass.becomes!(subclass)` to force the change but don't know how to put that in a `FactoryGirl` callback in a way that will actually return the converted object.

Comment: What does your `animal` declaration look like in `Zoo`? You might be able to change that declaration to return the child class instead of the parent class.

Comment: Can you change your test suite to { ["Dog", "Cat"] }.sample.class?

Comment: @HashRocket in what way would that help? @kcdragon In that specific example a `Zoo` has_one `Animal` and I test that a job properly sets that Zoo's animal. But, it is irrelevant, as I mentioned I am getting failing tests all throughout my test suite bc multiple tests that expect the `Animal` to be the one originally created with `FactoryGirl` are now instead getting back a `Cat` or a `Dog`. I understand *why*, I'm wondering if there's something I can do to ensure they match the originally created `Animal` rather than having to specify the type everywhere (especially when it shouldn't matter).

Comment: You want to return Animal from your factory instead of Dog or Cat correct?

Comment: Yes. Do you mean to add `.sample.class` at the end of the factory definition? `type` in the factory refers to the literal `type` column which sets the subclass.

Comment: Then if ```type``` sets the actual subclass, you should be able to call superclass on it and it should return 'Animal'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force the superclass factory to return an instance of the subclass by using `initialize_with`

Ex:

```
initialize_with do
  klass = type.constantize
  klass.new(attributes)
end
```